# Combining multiple similar COM objects in single managed wrapper

Tags: c#, interface, com, delegates

I'm writing a managed application (using .NET) which is loaded and executed in COM server. Inside the application, I have to interact with several COM interfaces/objects (provided by COM server). These COM interfaces share a set of methods with identical signature and behavior, the only difference is internal context. For example, COM interface definition from interop library would look like:

```
interface IComInterface1 {
    Object GetObject(String str, Int32 someInt);
    // more methods are defined
}
interface IComInterface2 {
    Object GetObject(String str, Int32 someInt);
    // more methods are defined
}
```

These methods are somewhat raw and require additional coding (like allocating/releasing resources, ensure method call sequence, etc.) and their processing is identical for both COM interfaces.

My goal is to write a single and unified managed (in C#) object which will hide internal COM interface handling and expose only useful for application methods. And eliminate duplicate implementation of managed classes.

I've split this objective into two tasks:

1. Create managed class that keeps methods for each shared method in private fields
2. Add public methods that expose useful functionality for business logic and will hide COM-specific method handling (allocating/releasing resources, ensure method call sequence, etc.)

Interface method processing is identical in both cases. Here is what I come with:

```
class MyManagedWrapper {
    readonly Func<String, Int32, Object> _getObject;
    <...> // additional funcs for every shared method

    public MyManagedWrapper(IComInterface1 comObj) {
        _getObject = comObj.GetObject;
        // assign more methods to funcs
    }
    public MyManagedWrapper(IComInterface2 comObj) {
        _getObject = comObj.GetObject;
        // assign more methods to funcs
    }

    public String GetUsefulData() {
        // here I no longer care about which interface I'm using, because
        // I'm going to call only funcs, hide COM management routine
        // and produce return value which is relevant for business logic
    }
}
```

This object's lifetime equals to COM server lifetime.

I believe this is a working solution and my primary concern is Func delegate invocation performance overhead. The COM server my application runs in is somewhat performance-critical and I have to ensure that I'm adding minimum possible performance overhead. That is, I can't use reflection (explicitly or implicitly) at runtime.

And I have two questions:

1. Does `Func` invocation add extra performance penalty comparing to direct method invocation on COM objects?
2. Do I need to keep the passed COM object reference (after assigning its methods to delegates in constructor) to avoid it from being garbage collected at runtime?

Comment: Did you tried what would happen if you would introduced another interface (not COM) which would have all the methods and then COM interface would be derived from it ?
`interace IDotNetInterface { /*common methods*/}` and then `interface IComInterface1  :  IDotNetInterface { /*repeat methods with right attribiutes */ }` and `interface IComInterface2  :  IDotNetInterface { /*repeat methods with right attribiutes */  }`

Comment: I can't modify COM interfaces, they are provided by operating system.

Comment: yes, you can ... you may dissasebly COM interop assebly and modify ... all it needs is right CLSID and eventually dispatch attributes

Comment: wouldn't you mind to elaborate how can I do this?

Comment: Why don't IComInterface1 and IComInterface2 derive from a common interface IComSomeBaseInterface with the common method(s) Object GetObject(String str, Int32 someInt);? This is what interface are for, and you can have multiple interface inheritance in most languages

Comment: if you have reference to COM library you can choose `EmbedInteropTypes` then istead using generated interop library the COM types would be added as generated code into your assembly .... http://selvin.pl/COMInterop.png ...IVATElement is a COM object but it's in my assebly ... i'm using  `EmbedInteropTypes`  but it can be done with hand-crafted code ...

Comment: `Why don't IComInterface1 and IComInterface2 derive from a common interface IComSomeBaseInterface`. I don't know. They first were defined in NT4 and haven't changed since then.

Comment: could you provide real names of the interface and object (since it's windows type there should be no problem) and given method which you use  I would try to check if its possible and eventually provide some example

Comment: one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/certif/nn-certif-icertserverpolicy and second: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/certif/nn-certif-icertserverexit.

Comment: Ok  so 1) yes, but it's nothing really. 2) no, why would they be GC'ed if they are still referenced. Note since they're IDispatch interfaces (late binding) , you could also use C# dynamic keyword like `dynamic obj = CreateObj1orObj2(); obj.DoSomething()`

Comment: [It will not work ;/](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MP0boW)  I forgot that same inheritance in interfaces just hides same method(it is not virtual)